# User not showing up in Global Address List?

Tags: exchange-2010

I have a user that is listed in All Users, but no matter what I do, they do not seem to be showing up in the Global Address List. I have forced updates, and refreshed the GAL multiple times, but this single user will not show up.

Why is the user not showing up in the GAL, and how can I remedy the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure the account is not ticked to be hided in the global's address list. Check your console.

[image]

Image took from [there](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000775)

Comment: I've already confirmed that the box is unchecked for the user.

Comment: @toolshed then check in OWA, if hes there and not in Outlook, be sure the client can download the GAL. (On the Tools menu, point to Send/Receive, and then click Download Address Book)

Comment: @toolshed or check that KB to be sure the OAB is really downloaded in the Outlook. (kb tagger for 0365, but it give the correct step)

Comment: Which KB article are you referring to?

Comment: @toolshed oops, sorry, forgot to paste the reference; KB2429946 or check that blog article https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2012/08/10/outlook-fails-to-download-oab/

Comment: The problem has been fixed. Apparently, the email address in AD must match the primary email address in Exchange. I will mark this BA, as that last link may be helpful to others in troubleshooting issues.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you asking about the correct thing - as there is no "refreshing" of the GAL. The GAL is built on the fly in real time and is seen by Outlook out of cached mode and in OWA.

In most cases what you see on the client is the OAB.

Therefore you need to be sure what you are looking at. Check the address book through OWA. Does the user show there? If so, then the issue is probably with the OAB. If the user does not show in OWA then the issue could be with the user account.

Comment: Yes, the user is in the address book when accessed via OWA. So, I've isolated the issue to being the OAB, but not sure why the one user is not listed.

Comment: Maybe you can review the last time when OAB were updated, and maybe try to update/rebuild that https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7725.how-to-quickly-rebuild-an-exchange-2010-offline-address-book.aspx